# CATextLayer foregroundColor animation don't work on iOS9 but work on iOS10 or high

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

CATextLayer `foregroundColor` animation don't work on `iOS9` but work normal on `iOS10`  or high version! I don't know  what's wrong with my code!

**Code as follow:**

```
- (void)addAnimationOnLayer:(CATextLayer*)layer{
CABasicAnimation *colorAn = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"foregroundColor"];

colorAn.fromValue = (id)NeColor333333.CGColor;
colorAn.toValue = (id)NeColor999999.CGColor;


CABasicAnimation *sizeAn = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"fontSize"];
sizeAn.fromValue = @16.0;
sizeAn.toValue = @12.0;


CAKeyframeAnimation *keyAn = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
keyAn.values = @[[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:layer.position],[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(layer.position.x, layer.position.y - 16)]];
keyAn.keyTimes =@[@0.0,@1.0];

CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
group.animations = @[colorAn, keyAn, sizeAn];
group.duration = 0.4;
group.repeatCount = 1;
group.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
group.removedOnCompletion = NO;

[layer addAnimation:group forKey:nil];
}
```

Comment: It's a little hard to diagnose iOS 9 these days. I verified that it does work as intended on iOS 12, which matches what you said. Can you try to commit **only** a `foregroundColor` animation to your text layer with the other animations (and no animation group)? Does that work as expected?

Comment: iOS9  only animation `foregroundColor `  does not work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a CALayer, and set CALayer mask is a CATextLayer, you an change CALayer backgroundColor with animation.

Comment: also can use[CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:1.0];
//    [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
    self.textLayer.foregroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    self.textLayer.fontSize = 50;
    [CATransaction commit];